# An error occurred in the server after trying to upload an image that I downloaded from Reddit

Tags: bug, images, error-message, uploader

I use Chrome on a Google pixel 6 with Android 11.
When I download an image via the Reddit application and try to upload to a Stack Exchange post, I get this error message:

[image]

Demo:
https://youtube.com/shorts/yqk1vcUDn7A

Links used in the demo:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/USCIS/comments/tt9wkg/los_angeles_n_400_time_line
- https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/23989/164

Since it says the error is on the server side, I'm reporting this as a bug.

I don't have this issue on my phone when uploading images that weren't downloaded from the Reddit application.

Comment: Just to verify, if you copy the link of that image from reddit and then paste that link in the image uploader here on SE, the image gets uploaded correctly, right? Because for me it does. So the only difference would then be the "Reddit application" and it is likely to be some oddness in that application. Not something SE has to fix.

Comment: @rene SE can fix the error message. I can't copy the link in the Reddit app, but likely works indeed.

Comment: What do they need to fix? That the error message reads: "No Franck, we're not processing your silly images that you butchered with your Reddit app!"

Comment: @rene "An error occurred in the server" is incorrect.

Comment: Why? It did occur on the server. It is the only place it can find out something went belly up. What do you expect it to say or do?

Comment: @rene in that case it should be able to process that image.

Comment: No, why? The Reddit App screwed the image from SE perspective, any app or user could have flipped bits in the upload stream. It can't process the image because the bytes it received don't make sense. The onus is on you to figure out what the Reddit App does to an image, then formulate a feature request for SE to support images that are scrambled by the Reddit app or file a bug report at Reddit's end that they need to preserve image streams as is.

Comment: @rene why do you think that reddit screwed the image? It opens fine on my phone. Anyway if it did, the error message could simply say that the image is invalid.

Comment: We established in act 1 that the Reddit application is the thing that makes or brakes the image upload. That your phones uses a relaxed  image reader is not a valid reason for a bug report in the SE software.

Comment: @rene I disagree but I'm not going to spend my free time on a bug I was already kind enough to report also on my free time.

Comment: You try to upload something that is not an image. Try uploading an image, and paste the [link to this very question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377839). You will get this same error, because imgur server try to process it as image and fails. No bug here.

Comment: It is Sunday, I can spend all day on this. Let's assume for a moment that it is an bug on the SE side, for example due to certain meta data (EXIF)  being added / present in a jpeg. If that is the case the Reddit app is the example that expose the bug but other cases might exist in the wild. In that case it would be useful to have the difference between the image as created by the Reddit app vs a direct linked image. That allows you / us to make this less about the Reddit application and more about acceptable meta data in the supported image formats

Comment: Here is the real bug: [Server Error: Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420821/server-error-failed-to-upload-image-an-error-occurred-on-the-server) that occurs with all images afaik.

Comment: @JasonLiam This is a much older bug report from six months ago. The issue you link to is a fresh one that just came up yesterday.